# getFormulas() and setFormulas() convert references to #REF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, importrange

I have a problem with my spreadsheet not refreshing an `=IMPORTRANGE` formula. I've tried all the tricks with sharing permissions and spreadsheet settings, but they don't work for me.

What I'm trying to do instead is create a simple macro that wipes the formula and re-enters it to refresh the import. When I run my macro, my formulas turns into `#REF`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var startingSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var importRange = ss.getRangeByName("MasterImport");
var importFormulas = importRange.getFormulas();
importRange.clearContent();
importRange.setFormulas(importFormulas);
```

My formula in named range "MasterImport" looks like this afterwards:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(#REF!, index(indirect(index(#REF!, match("asset_tab", #REF!, 0))),
    match(#REF!, indirect(index(#REF!, match("series_id", #REF!, 0))), 0)))
```

Comment: Give an example of what the formulas should be, and also the values that are read into memory: set a breakpoint on the `importRange.clearContent()` line, debug-execute the function in the Script Editor manually, and review the variables in the "watch" section at the bottom of the page. (Edit these bits of info into your question)

Comment: Add a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` after clearing content.

Comment: thank you @TheMaster! Worked for me. I'll add it as a self-answer for more visibility in case others are curious

Answer (score 0):

@TheMaster's suggestion worked perfectly. Here is the final code:

```
var importRange = ss.getRangeByName("MasterImport");
var importFormulas = importRange.getFormulas();
importRange.clearContent();
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
importRange.setFormulas(importFormulas);
```